# Updating another table in an Oracle Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I've prepared the following trigger create statement yet it does not compile.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UpdIssueTypScrSchmSeq
  AFTER INSERT 
  ON ISSUETYPESCREENSCHEME
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  maxID NUMBER(18,0);
BEGIN
    select max(ID) into maxID from ISSUETYPESCREENSCHEME;

    UPDATE SEQUENCE_VALUE_ITEM 
    SET SEQ_ID = maxID + 1
    WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'IssueTypeScreenSchemeEntity';
END;
```

I keep getting error messsages saying "maxID must be declared".

Anybody know what is wrong?

Propbably does not make a difference but I am working with SQL Developer on Windows.

Comment: Is it _temp table_ `maxID` ?

Comment: can you add a statement that creates the table ISSUETYPESCREENSCHEME so we can see the column names and types?

Comment: This seems like really bad design; you appear to be replicating the functionality of sequences - can't you switch to use them? Also, you're doing the update after every row; shouldn't it be after each statement, esp if you're inserting multiple rows in one go? Also, it would be better if you could avoid the need for the variable by combining the select statement into the update statement. P.S. If you absolutely must use this trigger, I sure hope you have some means of preventing concurrent inserts into the table, otherwise race conditions ahoy!

Comment: OK, answers here: 1-maxID is a variable, not a temptable. 2-ISSUETYPESCREENSCHEME table has 3 columns, 1 ID column integer and 2 text columns. 3- Unfortunately this is not my database, it is the db of an existing application so I have no say on the design. I believe I can change the trigger to work after each statement, that should work fine.